# Changing color through expression SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to change the background color of a row where the value is more than 1 with an expression. I have copied the following code from an earlier thread related to this issue but is not working for me.

```
= IIF(fields!OpenstaandeTijdInUren.value = >1, "Orange")
```

When I try to save it I get the following error statement:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of "fields" and "value" you need to capitalise the v and f, so the correct expression would be `=IIF(Fields!OpenstaandeTijdInUren.Value >=1, "Orange")`, although from the wording of your question, you might want to use `>` instead of `>=`. SSRS expressions are case sensitive. You should probably also put something in the false side of the check, maybe "Transparent".

`=IIF(Fields!OpenstaandeTijdInUren.Value >=1, "Orange","Transparent")`

Comment: It isn't anything to do with the capitalisation (VBA is case-insensitive), there are two problems with the question's expresson: (1) the comparison expresson has incorrectly `= >1` whereas yours has the correct `>=1`; and (2) it is missing the False part of the `IIF` function call, and yours has `"Transparent"` as that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this -

```
=IIF(Fields!OpenstaandeTijdInUren.Value > 1, "Orange", "No Color")
```

Comment: checkout this solution(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b697eed3-05c1-4860-a6d1-d0cdf9b5972d/return-statement-in-a-functiongetor-operator-must-return-a-valuequestion?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: Had to use Transparant instead of no color